# Shiro Security, multiple realms which authorization info is taken?

Tags: java, security, authentication, authorization, shiro

i am using two realms in my shiro security protected java application. One is supporting my OAuthToken and the other one supports UsernamePasswordToken. Now when my users authenticate themselves using a OAuthToken, the doGetAuthenticationInfo method of my OAuthRealm is called, but the doGetAuthorizationInfo of my **PasswordRealm** is called, can anyone tell me, why?

Kind regards
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the method [isPermitted()](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/AuthorizingRealm.html#isPermitted%28org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection,%20java.lang.String%29) in your Realm. Shiro checks each declared realm with this method whether current realm is permitted to authorize an user or not. You could implement this method somehow like that:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean isPermitted(PrincipalCollection principals, String permission) {
    if (principals.fromRealm("realm name").isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return super.isPermitted(principals, permission);
    }
}
```